# Sphinx documentation - creating table showing latest api requests

Tags: python, python-sphinx

Hello I want to generate in Sphinx a status overview table - one column including information if the last api request was successful  (shown as check mark) and another column including the related date.
For example a Quandl request was successful:

```
+---------------+--------------------+--------------+
| Data provider | Successful request | Last request |
+---------------+--------------------+--------------+
| Quandl        | ✅                 | 2020-05-12   |
| Eurostat      | ✅                 | 2020-05-1    |
| ...           | ❌                 | ...          |
+---------------+--------------------+--------------+
```

Do you have ideas how to implement this in sphinx. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close. You were missing row separators.

```
+---------------+--------------------+--------------+
| Data provider | Successful request | Last request |
+---------------+--------------------+--------------+
| Quandl        | ✅                 | 2020-05-12   |
+---------------+--------------------+--------------+
| Eurostat      | ✅                 | 2020-05-1    |
+---------------+--------------------+--------------+
| ...           | ❌                 | ...          |
+---------------+--------------------+--------------+
```

For more options, see the Sphinx documentation on [tables](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/basics.html#tables).